# Number of unique 12-item groups from pool of 9 items?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Sorry if the title is worded ambiguously. My question, put a different way, is:

Given a set of $9$ different items, and $12$ "slots" to fill using those items, how do I figure out how many unique combinations of $12$ items can be made (allowing for repetition of individual items within groups, but not whole groups)?

Additionally, is there a formal way to express this? n choose k is my first instinct, but obviously 9 choose 12 is 0. I feel like there is something obvious I'm missing.

To elaborate a bit further, if my nine items are A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, and I:

$AAAAAAAAAAAB$, $AAAABCDEFGHI$, and $AAAABBBBCCCC$ are unique groups of items.
$BAAAAAAAAAAA$, $IHGFEDCBAAAA$, and $BBBBAAAACCCC$ are identical to the first groups, so they are not unique if the first three have already been accounted for.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: Is it $165$ the answer

Comment: Can it be 0? Certain element absent

Comment: The sets to be counted must include 12 items, but not all 9 items from the available pool must be used. As in my example, AAAAAAAAAAAB would constitute a valid 12-item group. I apologize if I'm confused, Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Ya thanks you can see my answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its like finding positive integer solutions so $x_1+...x_9=12$ so total ways are given by a binomial formula ${n+k-1\choose k-1}$ so here $n=12,k=9$ so its ${20 \choose 8}=125970$.

Comment: I am clearing from asker whether all elements have to be present or not . If it can be 0 then ofc you are right

Comment: You are right i only read the question thanks

Comment: I believe that formula is exactly what I was looking for, but I think you made a mistake with the arithmetic. Shouldn't it be {20 \choose 8}=125970

Comment: ${20 \choose 8}=125970$, rather.

Comment: No its n+k-1 ..